# Division in select query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below given if my table

```
create table batches ( batchid int,free smallint,qty int)


INSERT INTO batches VALUES (2329, 0, 100);
INSERT INTO batches VALUES (2329, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO batches VALUES (2331, 0, 75);
INSERT INTO batches VALUES (2331, 1, 4);
```

this table will return

```
 batchid free qty 
 2329    0    100
 2329    1    10
 2331    0    75
 2331    1    4
```

---

need to perform *division* on *column* `qty`
I.e in this case 100 should divide with 10 (batchid should be same ) 100/10 (here 10  is the `qty` where `free = 1`)

EXPECTED RESULT

```
Batchid  freelimit
2329     10
2331     18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html)

```
with a as (
    select 
      batchid,qty 
    from batches  
    where  free = 0 order by batchid 
)
, b as (
    select 
      batchid,qty 
    from batches  
    where  free = 1order by batchid 
)
select 
  batchid, floor((a.qty/b.qty))::real as freelimit 
from a inner join b using(batchid)
```

---

<kbd>[**SQLFIDDLE-DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/85dd0/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You want a self-join here:

```sql
WITH d(batchid, free, qty) AS (
    VALUES (2329::int, 0::int2, 100::int), (2329, 1, 10),
           (2331, 0, 75),  (2331, 1, 4)
)
SELECT a.batchid, a.qty/b.qty
  FROM d a
  JOIN d b ON a.batchid=b.batchid AND b.free=1
 WHERE a.free=0;
```